# Swift optional in label

Tags: swift, option-type

I have this code right here

```
let fundsreceived = String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.campaign?["CurrentFunds"]!)
cell.FundsReceivedLabel.text = "$\(funds received)"
```

It is printing out `Optional(1000)`

I have already added `!` to the variable but the optional isn't going away. Any idea what have i done wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because the parameter you are passing to

```
String(stringInterpolationSegment:)
```

is an **Optional**.

> Yes, you did a `force unwrap` and you still have an `Optional`...

Infact if you decompose your line...

```
let fundsreceived = String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.campaign?["CurrentFunds"]!)
```

into the following equivalent statement...

```
let value = self.campaign?["CurrentFunds"]! // value is an Optional, this is the origin of your problem
let fundsreceived = String(stringInterpolationSegment: value)
```

you find out that `value` is an `Optional`!

### Why?

1. Because `self.campaign?` **produces** an `Optional`
2. Then `["CurrentFunds"]` **produces** another `Optional`
3. Finally your force `unwrap` **removes** one `Optional`

> So **2 Optionals** - **1 Optional** = **1 Optional**

### First the ugliest solution I can find

I am writing this solution just to tell you what you should **NOT** do.

```
let fundsreceived = String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.campaign!["CurrentFunds"]!)
```

As you can see I replaced your conditional unwrapping `?` with a force unwrapping `!`. Just do not do it at home!

### Now the good solution

Remember, you should avoid this guy `!` everytime you can!

```
if let
    campaign = self.campaign,
    currentFunds = campaign["CurrentFunds"] {
        cell.FundsReceivedLabel.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment:currentFunds)
}
```

1. Here we are using `conditional binding` to transform the optional `self.campaign` into a `non optional` constant (when possible).
2. Then we are transforming the value of `campaign["CurrentFunds"]` into a `non optional type` (when possible).

Finally, if the IF does succeed, we can safely use `currentFunds` because it is not optional.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Unwrap it with `if let` this way:

```
if let fundsreceived = String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.campaign?["CurrentFunds"]!){
    cell.FundsReceivedLabel.text = "$\(fundsreceived)"
}
```

Look at this simple example:

```
let abc:String = "AnyString"  //here abc is not an optional

if let cde = abc {           //So you will get error here  Bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type 
    println(cde)
}
```

But if you declare it as an optional like this:

```
let abc:String? = "AnyString"
```

now you can unwrap it without any error like this:

```
if let cde = abc {
    println(cde)    //AnyString
}
```

Hope this example will help.

Comment: I got this error Bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type