# Label Printing Optional() Even With Force Unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I'm creating my first Swift test app and I'm getting this: http://prntscr.com/9ldyqc

Here is my function when you hit enter after typing your name in the text box:

```
@IBAction func onExit(nameTextField: UITextField!) {
    nameLabel.text = "Hello, \(nameTextField.text)"
}
```

I read this: [Swift optional in label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939516/swift-optional-in-label) but it confused me. What I'm getting from it is that there is another variable somewhere that is still optional but I can't figure it out. All explanations help. Thanks :)

Comment: not posting this as an answer since it is tooo basic - use `nameTextField.text!` - note the added `!`.

Comment: Ohhhhh thanks for finding that. I didn't see it. It's nice having someone finding something you can't see yourself in the code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You're force unwrapping the textfield, not it's text property which is likely declared:

```
var text: String?
```

Instead, do this:

```
let name = nameTextField.text ?? "Default"
nameLabel.text = "Hello, \(name)"
```